Stickiness on AWS lambda instance
We're serving a resource behind an API of this form /item/{id}/{query_spec}.
Each query_spec involves some local compute server-side, and each item is quite heavy, so we keep data locally (memory+file) to avoid fetching item data from storage (s3) for each query. We actually also have some warmup to do some prefetch when possible. Items are relatively short-lived, meaning the majority of incoming queries (but not all) are targeting the most recent items (a new one every 10mn).
Currently, this is served by a fleet of containers (on ECS), but we have traffic spikes and the scaling is not reactive enough. The result is that we're over-provisioning this service a lot.
I'm wondering whether AWS Lambda could be an option here.
From my understanding, we can use /tmp to keep some data locally between invocations, to avoid refetching all the time.
But /tmp is not that big, so the best would be to route all the queries for a particular item id to lambda instances that recently served data for it (they would have data locally already).
Is there a way to configure this kind of "stickiness" on api-to-lambda routing ?
Any other design consideration that could help ?
Update:
we do have a CDN in front to cache the recurring requests for (item_id,query_spec) pairs

I don't think so, no. Each Lambda should assume it's a cold started instance. It can cache data locally, but you should expect a low cache hit rate if you have high concurrency. The usual option there is to store data in a fast store like DynamoDB or memcache equivalents AWS offers.

It sounds like what you actually need is some sort of caching in front of your API, like a CDN (AWS CloudFront, or Cloudflare, etc.) so that if the same request comes in multiple times, the CDN can just return the response your API sent last time, without actually invoking your backend server again. If you are using AWS API Gateway, then adding CloudFront is as simple as enabling caching in the API settings.

@MarkB indeed. We do have a CDN in place already (question updated)

Then the scenario you are worried about shouldn't be happening. The CDN should be serving those subsequent requests. Is that not the case?

@MarkB there are various possible query_specs for each item. For each new item, we have a bunch of new query_specs to respond to.

One way is to mount a EFS (it's like a network drive) to your containers as it starts, and you save the file in the EFS so that it available to all the containers without re-downloading the same file. This would also makes your container's "warmup" faster since the file is already available.

That's a possible option, with the caveat of concurrent writes on the first fetch and cache.
